Change of variables in Euler-Lagrange equations for a field
From the Euler-Lagrange equations for the field Lagrangian density:  $$L = \frac{1}{2} (\partial_{\mu}\phi)^2 - V(\phi)$$ we arrive at the Euler-Lagrange equations: $$\frac{\partial V(\phi)}{\partial \phi} = \left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} + \nabla^2 \right) \phi$$ If we assume $\phi$ is purely a function of $\rho = \sqrt{t^2 + \vec{x}^2}$, then the PDE should be rewritable as: $$\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial \rho^2} + \frac{3}{\rho}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \rho} = \frac{\partial V(\phi)}{\partial \phi}$$ When I try to substitute in using the chain rule ie. $$\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial \rho^2} = \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial t^2} \frac{\partial^2 t}{\partial \rho^2}$$ I can't seem to get the proper result. Is this not the proper way to substitute in? Thank yu in advance

The chain-rule tells you that $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} = \frac{d\phi}{d\rho}\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}$ and similar the $x_i$-derivatives. This should be your starting point. If you then take the $t$-derivative of this you get $\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial t^2} = \frac{d^2\phi}{d\rho^2}\left(\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}\right)^2 + \frac{d\phi}{d\rho}\left(\frac{\partial^2\rho}{\partial t^2}\right)$. Then do the same for the $x_i$'s (its basically the same expression with $t\to x_i$) and evaluate the $\rho$-derivatives.

Thanks! When I do this I end with a $\frac{1}{2\rho}$ where the $\frac{3}{\rho}$ is. Have I missed something obvious?

Look like you forgot a factor of $2$ in the differentiation (i.e. $\rho_t = (2t)/(2\rho) = t/\rho$). Also don't forget you have $3$ components of $\vec{x}$. I.e. $\nabla^2 \phi = \phi_{x_1x_1} + \phi_{x_2x_2} + \phi_{x_3x_3}$. For the $\phi'$ term each of these will contribute $(\rho^2 - x_i^2)/\rho^3$ which together with a $(\rho^2 - t^2)/\rho^3$ when summed together will give you the $1+3-1 = 3$ that you want.

Yep! I've got it worked out now; thank you.
